# phalcon-devtools Error in Scaffolding Undefined index: modelsNamespace

Tags: php, phalcon

I cannot scaffold using webtools in phalcon-devtools. It returns this stack trace

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: modelsNamespace in D:\Apps\phalcon-devtools\scripts\Phalcon\Builder\Scaffold.php on line 173
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  141920  {main}( )   ..\webtools.php:0
2   0.0010  196872  Phalcon\Web\Tools::main( )  ..\webtools.php:26
3   0.0018  230912  handle ( )  ..\Tools.php:322
4   0.0019  252888  dispatch ( )    ..\Tools.php:322
5   0.0027  276096  ScaffoldController->generateAction( )   ..\Tools.php:0
6   0.0041  454728  Phalcon\Builder\Scaffold->build( )  ..\ScaffoldController.php:67
```

Is it a bug in phalcon-devtools or misconfigured in my phalcon-devtools?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but this is just a notice and it is not the reason for program halt.
I think the reason is that in your config file you used `../app/models` for your models directory just like me :-P , but phalcon-devtools isn't in your project directory and it can't find such a folder for creating model in it.
by changing model directory to `__DIR__/../app/models` the problem will be solved.

Comment: I think this issues has been solved in the new version of phalcon dev tools

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the line n 541 on phalcon-devtools\scripts\Phalcon\Builder\scaffold.php

```
$options['controllersNamespace'] = 'YOURNAMESPACE\Frontend\Controllers';
```